# I cannot see my group in ribbon in list view form? XML

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, xml

I have the following XML trying to create a new ribbon group but I don't know what is going wrong here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
Id="CustomRibbonTab"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"
RegistrationId="100"
RegistrationType="List">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.Tabs._children">
      <Tab
        Id="Ribbon.CustomTab"
        Title="Custom Tab"
        Description="Custom Tab !!!"
        Sequence="501">
        <Scaling
          Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling">
          <MaxSize
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.MaxSize"
            GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium"/>
          <Scale
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Scaling.CustomTabScaling"
            GroupId="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
            Size="OneLargeTwoMedium" />
        </Scaling>
        <Groups Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.Groups">
          <Group
            Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup"
            Description="Custom Group!"
            Title="Custom Group"
            Sequence="52"
            Template="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
            <Controls Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.Controls">
              <Button
                Id="Ribbon.CustomTab.CustomGroup.CustomButton"
                Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
                Sequence="15"
                Description=""
                LabelText="Custom Button"
                Image32by32="/_layouts/images/PPEOPLE.GIF"
                TemplateAlias="cust1"/>

            </Controls>
          </Group>
        </Groups>
      </Tab>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
      <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.CustomTemplate">
        <Layout
          Title="OneLargeTwoMedium"
          LayoutTitle="OneLargeTwoMedium">
          <Section Alignment="Top" Type="OneRow">
            <Row>
              <ControlRef DisplayMode="Large" TemplateAlias="cust1" />
            </Row>
          </Section>
        </Layout>
      </GroupTemplate>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomTab.CustomButtonCommand"
       CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
  </CommandUIExtension>
 </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: please specify which error are you getting, or output shown to your ribbon ?!

Comment: I got no output at all but if I change the `Location ` to `Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"` and 
`RegistrationId="101"` it works but not in my list but in my all documents librarys

Comment: are you tried to put as RegistrationId="yourList"

Comment: I have a custom list and its ID seems to be 100 but i don't know exactly

Comment: you mentioned above you are used 101 try to pick up the id of your list that you said 100 and check if it's worked

Comment: it was my mistake 100 is for documents library and for generic list is 101 i tried with 101 but it does not worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43640/discussion-between-nderon-hyseni-and-m-qassas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of the `registration ID` value for

- `Document Library` code is `101`
- `Generic list` code is `100`

This code is the `template ID` so you will apply your custom action for all list with this template id.

if you tried to do it for a specific list you should

- Create a `list content type`.
- Attach it to your list.
- Get it's ID and set it in `Registration ID`.
- Change your `Registration Type` from `List` to `ContentType`.

Comment: After I followed your steps, I made it to work. Thank you so much you saved my life